MS Graph API to send a reply email with the sender cc'ed and move this email to a folder
I am struggling with how to approach this. I am automating a task which includes sending an email from a shared mailbox then filing it to a folder in the shared mailbox. Because my users like to see the chain of emails in a single folder they typically cc the sending mailbox so it shows up in the inbox and they will file this away in that folder. My approach is to just create a copy of the sent mail item to the folder since the message created from the cc we do not know when that will actually make it to the inbox and circle back so I do not want my code to hang keep checking for this email.
So from my first take I have learned that I do not get a Id back from sending a reply email. Based on stackoverflow I have learned I need to create a reply email so I have the following code:
    public async Task<Models.Email?> SendReplyToEmailAsync(string mailBox, string messageId, AddEmailDTO email)
    {
        var requestBody = new CreateReplyPostRequestBody
        {
            Message = new Message
            {
                ToRecipients = email.To?.Select(contact => new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        Name = contact.Name
                    }
                }).ToList(),
                CcRecipients = email.Cc?.Select(contact => new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        Name = contact.Name
                    }
                }).ToList(),
                BccRecipients = email.Cc?.Select(contact => new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.Models.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = contact.EmailAddress,
                        Name = contact.Name
                    }
                }).ToList(),
                Subject = email.Subject,
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                    Content = email.Body,
                },
                
            },
        };

        var result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages[messageId].CreateReply.PostAsync(requestBody);
        
        if(result != null) 
        {
            await _graphServiceClient.Me.Messages[result.Id].Send.PostAsync();
            return await GetEmailAsync(mailBox, result.Id!); 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

My issue is does this Id of the draft result stay constant after being sent such that I can use to use Send.PostAsync() as shown in my example? Then would I be able to use this Id again for copying the sent message later using this example I put togeher:
    public async Task CopyEmailByFolderIdAsync(string mailBox, string messageId, string folderId)
    {
        var requestBody = new CopyPostRequestBody
        {
            DestinationId = folderId,
            
        };

        var result = await _graphServiceClient.Users[mailBox].Messages[messageId].Copy.PostAsync(requestBody);
    }

Lastly, when seeing this similar issue on stackoverflow it seems users say to use a immutable id to reference back to later and I found this solution using older versions of MS Graph API and I am struggling how to implement this into my solution and v5+ MS Graph API:
            var test = await userRequestBuilder.Messages.Request().Header("Prefer", "IdType=\"ImmutableId\"").AddAsync(message, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false)

In particular, I am not sure how to add Prefer: IdType="ImmutableId" to the header PostAsync request in my example and once I add that is result.Id and if not how do I access Immutable Id when doing future request such as copying the sent email?
